# In regards to file size, how best can I record and embed an OSX screen capture?

Tags: html, macos, gif, filesize, webm

I have a very lightweight frontend-only JavaScript app hosted on Github Pages. I'd like to take a (30sec, 60fps, soundless, native res) screen capture of a 300x300px area of my screen, and embed it into my website's HTML.

I tried capturing with GIPHY, and it worked. However, adding the file doubled my application size. What can I do to shrink my filesize? Should I try to capture as a gifv? webm? mp4? Or try something else?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just host the giphy elsewhere?

Comment: Because the app needs to be self-contained. Sorry I didn't mention that earlier.